# Python hangs when running in a conda env on git bash

Tags: python, terminal, git-bash

I want to use my conda environment in gitbash.
I have add my conda.sh path in my ~/.bashrc. This is correctly recognized as I can now run `conda activate` and the `base` environment will be activated. Now I can run command such as `pip install jupyterlab` and it will correctly run. However, when I type `python` the terminal just hangs indefinitely. `which python` correctly returns `/c/Users/valer/anaconda3/python`. Similarly, the Anaconda Prompt returns to `where python`: `C:\Users\valer\anaconda3\python.exe`
If I type `python` through the Anaconda Prompt it works normally.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Vaaal88 suggest, add `alias python='winpty python.exe'` to your ~/.bash_profile (or ~/.bashrc in older versions of git bash)

My ~/.bash_profile looks like:

```
alias python='winpty python.exe'

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
if [ -f '/c/Users/hugo/miniconda3/Scripts/conda.exe' ]; then
    eval "$('/c/Users/hugo/miniconda3/Scripts/conda.exe' 'shell.bash' 'hook')"
fi
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. In addition to your story, I'm able to run scripts.

So, this hangs:

```
$ python
```

But this works:

```
$ python script.py
```

Comment: Hi, I did find a workaround in the meantime. Try running `winpty python.exe`. That works for me. Of course you can alias it in the `.bashrc`. Let me know!

Comment: Could you tell us why the second one works?

Comment: I guess that the second one works, because it doesn't use the python shell. I think the python shell doesn't support Git Bash and using winpty fixes that. However, I'm not an expert on this matter.